# Does DTOs comes under decorator pattern?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, decorator, dto

I have Entity and DTO classes defined in two different Entity and DTO packages as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Foo", schema="REF_DATA")
public class Foo extends BaseEntity {
 private Long fooId;
 private String fooName;
}


public class FooDto extends BaseDto {
 private Long fooId;
 private String fooName;
}
```

While returning values to the User, we are returning `DTOs` rather than `Entity` objects. For that we have declared the mapper and it's implementation as:

```
public interface DomainToDtoMapper<E extends BaseEntity, D extends BaseDto> {

   D mapDomainToDto(E domain);
}

public class FooDomainToDtoMapper implements DomainToDtoMapper<Foo, FooDto> {
    @Override
    public FooDto mapDomainToDto(Foo domain) {
        FooDto fooDto = new FooDto();
        FooDto.setfooId(domain.getfooId());
        FooDto.setfooName(domain.getfooName());
        return fooDto;
    }

}
```

And get list of all `Foo` objects call in the service layer looks something like:

```
@Override
public List<FooDto> getAllFoo() {
    return fooRepository.findAll().stream()
            .map(FooEntityDomainToDtoMapper::mapDomainToDto) // mapping entity to dto
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

My question is are we using `Decorator pattern` here? I know there is `Data Transfer Object Pattern` but since we are providing implementation for mapping, can we say it is decorator pattern? Or is there any other design pattern getting used here?

Comment: Transformation != decoration. Decoration maintains one object hierarchy. As you noted, [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) is its own pattern. Also consider, [Data Transfer Object Is a Shame](https://www.yegor256.com/2016/07/06/data-transfer-object.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a decorator pattern, because a decorator pattern

> allows behavior to be added to an individual object, dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the **same class**.

Since you map to another class it is not the same class.